# What's the difference between Illustration and Graphic Design?

Tags: illustration, terminology

What is the difference between ***graphic design*** and ***illustration***?
I ask because I want to know what to write in my social media biography.

Comment: see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_design) for starter

Comment: What do you think they are? Did you research the terms at all before posting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main purpose of graphic design is basically to send a message to an audience or to persuade them. They send the message by communicating visual information. A professional graphic designer is mostly working on layout, typography, branding and image development.

Illustration is a more creative work/visualization. Illustrators use drawings or picture to represent the text on the page or decorate it, also they can sometimes do both design work and illustration but not vice versa.